# Найти К-й по величине элемент (Java)

Tags: java, массивы, алгоритм

Нужно реализовать данный алгоритм:

> выбираем из списка наибольший элемент и помещаем его
> в конец списка. В оставшейся части выбираем наибольший элемент и
> помещаем его на второе место от конца списка. Продолжаем процедуру до
> тех пор, пока не дойдем до К-го по величине элемента.

Также дан псевдокод:

```
FindKthLargest(list,K,N)
list список для просмотра
N число элементов в списке
К порядковый номер по величине требуемого элемента
for i=1 to К do
largest=list[1]
largestLocation=1
for j=2 to N-(i-1) do
if list [j]>largest then
largest=list [j]
largestLocation=j
end if
end for
Swap(list[N-(i-1)],list[largestLocation])
end for
return largest
```

Вот, что вышло у меня:

```
package algorithm;
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {
     int[] arr =  { 12, 3, 5, 7, 4, 11, 26 };
     System.out.print("K'th largest element is " + findKthLargest(arr, 7, 3));
}
public static int findKthLargest(int[] list, int N, int K) {
    for(int i=0; i<K; i++) {
        int largest = list[1];
        int largestLocation=1;
        for(int j=1; j<N-(i-1); j++) {
            if(list[j]>largest) {
                largest=list[j];
                largestLocation = j;
            }
        }
        int temp = list[N-(i-1)];
        list[N-(i-1)] = list[largestLocation];
        list[largestLocation] = temp;
        return largest;
    }
    return 0;
}
}
```

Но он не хочет работать, выдавая ошибку *Index 7 out of bounds for length 7* на 6 и 13 строке. Никак не могу понять, как заставить его работать.

Comment: индексы в программировании начинаются с нуля, а не с единицы

Comment: на результат (или его отсутствие) это изменение не повлияло

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Основные ошибки в том, что последний элемент имеет индекс `N-1`, а также в том, что выполняется возврат из метода после первой же итерации.

Также следует отметить, что параметр `N` в методе излишний, так как фактически это `list.length`.  Кроме того, можно передавать массив `list` как vararg, тогда упростится вызов метода:

```java
public static int findKthLargest(int K, int ... list) {
    int N = list.length;
    for(int i = 0; i < K; i++) {
        int largest = list[0];
        int largestLocation = 0;
        for(int j = 1; j < N-i; j++) {
            if(list[j] > largest) {
                largest=list[j];
                largestLocation = j;
            }
        }

        int temp = list[N-i-1];
        list[N-i-1] = list[largestLocation];
        list[largestLocation] = temp;
    }
    return list[N - K];
}
```

Тест:

```
int K = 3;
System.out.println(K + "-й наибольший элемент: " + findKthLargest(3, 12, 3, 5, 7, 4, 11, 26));

int[] arr =  { 12, 12, 12, 14, 14, 11, 26};
System.out.println(4 + "-й наибольший элемент: " + findKthLargest(4, arr));
```

Вывод:

```
3-й наибольший элемент: 11
4-й наибольший элемент: 12
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, что даже пример привели. Всё работает

Answer (score 2):

Когда первый раз попадаете во второй цикл, вы пытаетесь пробежать больше элементов, чем есть в массиве

```
for(int j=1; j<N-(i-1); j++)
```

здесь N = 7, i = 0, получается 7 - (0 - 1) = 8

Как исправить?

1. -1 необходимо убрать из условия цикла
2. заменить 1 на 0 при инициализации largest и largestLocation
3. исправить условия при перемещении элементов массива чтобы не выходить за его размер

```
public static int findKthLargest(int[] list, int N, int K) {
    for(int i=0; i<K; i++) {
        int largest = list[0];
        int largestLocation=0;
        for(int j=1; j<N-i; j++) {
            if(list[j]>largest) {
                largest=list[j];
                largestLocation = j;
            }
        }
        int temp = list[(N-1)-i)];
        list[(N-1)-i] = list[largestLocation];
        list[largestLocation] = temp;
        return largest;
    }
    return 0;
}
```